# Pandas: How to search and remove a key value pair in a python dictionary for matching pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary listed below.

```
["key1" : "//This is an entry to be deleted", "key2" : "Good key", "key3", "Good key"]
```

For all values which starts with "//" are bad keys so they must  be deleted.

Please let me know if anybody did not get my issue.

Comment: it is not dictionary

Comment: {'Names': 'Survey', 'Root Folder': '//D{..}01.Survey', 'File Name': '//D:{..}\ist*.xlsx'}

this is the actual dictionary. It may not make sense to others that's why I recreated the dictionary for community purpose. And in the dictionary i want to ignore 'Root Folder' because I have commented it's value. All key and values are read from an Excel File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with filtering by `startswith`:

```
d = {"key1" : "//This is an entry to be deleted", "key2" : "Good key", "key3": "Good key"}

d = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if not v.startswith('//')}
print (d)
{'key2': 'Good key', 'key3': 'Good key'}
```

Use dictionary comprehension with filtering by `startswith`:

```
d = {"//key1" : "This is an entry to be deleted", "key2" : "Good key", "key3": "Good key"}

d = {k: v for k, v in dc.items() if not k.startswith('//')}
print (d)
{'key2': 'Good key', 'key3': 'Good key'}
```

Comment: But I want to remove the key only if "//" is in the beginning. If  I have a value that says "This is // value ", it still is a good key to me.

Comment: in brief what I am trying to do is, I have a data frame from an excel sheet, in which if I quote a cell with //, that particular cell is marked as commented out and the value is ignored.

Comment: @Bot001 - now checked comment under question, do you need omit some key:value pair by some key?

Comment: Yes, I need to omit key value pair by matching

Comment: @Bot001 - So solution working? Or is necessary add another condition?